# fullPage.js not detecting height of dynamic generated content when using scrollOverflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js for my website. About fullpage.js everything working fine. I want to open an div on click of pagniation. I am able to open div on click which contains YouTube video. But when div is visible browser scroll will be disabled I am not getting where I go wrong.

here is sample of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            verticalCentered: false,
            css3:false,
            navigation: true,
            normalScrollElements: '.text',
            navigationTooltips: ['tooltip1', 'tooltip2', 'tooltip3'],
            onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){

                var prevIndex = index - 1;
                var currentIndex = nextIndex - 1;

                $('#section'+currentIndex).css('transform', 'scale(1.2)');
                $('#section'+currentIndex).css('transition', 'all 5s ease-in');

                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#section'+prevIndex).css('transform', 'scale(1)');
                    $('#section'+prevIndex).css('transition', 'all 0.2s ease-in');
                },500);

            },
        });
    });
```

in jquery.fullpage.js

```
var li = '<li><a href="#' + link + '" onclick="displayDetails('+i+');"><span>' + tooltip + '</span></a>';
```

function :

```
function displayDetails(id)
  {
    $('#text').show();
  }
```

HTML code:

```
<style>
#text {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
    z-index:999;
    top: 300px;
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
<div id="text">
  <iframe width="480" height="270" class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6iNFimn4wFA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="480" height="270" class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jsd-mNTIukM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br>
  <iframe width="480" height="270" class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ylD-WFvRZkM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="480" height="270" class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g2YzRTAstPo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br>
  <iframe width="480" height="270" class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/98NqtVG-hFU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <iframe width="480" height="270" class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/O4weBTRCFzU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><br>
  <iframe width="480" height="270" class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/UVzEOsHT7XA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div id="fullpage">    
   <div class="section" id="section0"></div>
   <div class="section" id="section1"></div>
   <div class="section" id="section2"></div>
   <div class="section" id="section3"></div>
   <div class="section" id="section4"></div>
</div>
```

This code opens div as expected but scrolling to see last contents is not working. Instead of video if I enter text scroll works perfectly. As soon as I add video in div scroll stops working. I haven't set `overflow` property for `#text`. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should be using `scrollOverflow:true` rather than `normalScrollElements`.

> **scrollOverflow:**
>
> (default false) defines whether or not to create a scroll for the section in case its content is bigger than the height of it. When set to true, your content will be wrapped by the plugin. Consider using delegation or load your other scripts in the afterRender callback. In case of setting it to true, it requires the vendor plugin jquery.slimscroll.min and it should be loaded before the fullPage.js plugin. For example:

Then, fullPage.js is calculatingn the height of your sections on page load.
If the videos are not displayed on page load, fullPage.js won't know the content is changing until you tell it so.

Try this:

```
function displayDetails(id){
    $('#text').show();
    
   //forcing fullPage.js to recalculate dimensions.
    $.fn.fullpage.reBuild(); 
}
```

More about the [reBuild method](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#rebuild) in the docs:

> **reBuild()**
>
> Updates the DOM structure to fit the new window size or its contents.
> Ideal to use in combination with AJAX calls or external changes in the
> DOM structure of the site.

[See this example I made for you](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/487/)

Comment: not working yet. my `<div id="text">` is placed above `<div id="fullpage">`. Is is causing problem?

Comment: Mainly because you are using `normalScrollElements` instead of using `scrollOverflow:true`, that is what you should be using in this case.

Comment: Updated my answer. And added an example online.

Comment: thanks for jsfiddle. I get it but in example you mentioned videos in section which I don't want. I want videos to be display over the section that's why I wrote video code above `<div id="fullpage">`.

Comment: @Aakanksha well then you would need to be more specific in your question, as you didn't provide your HTML markup or mention anything about floating elements.

Comment: I just edited my question. Previously also I mentioned about floating element. Onclick div element is visible ant it's working fine. If floating div contains text, image scroll works as expected but as I add video tag or youtube video scroll stops working.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a defined height for `#text` or even 100%, and use `overflow:scroll`. If that's not working, then I'm sorry I can not help you more unless you reproduce your problem somewhere or add a link to your site.

Comment: @Aakanksha where do i have to click to get the floating element?

Comment: I changed my code as per your JSFiddle. It's working fine. One little change I want in it as once videos are shown I want scrolling to other sections disable and on close of video tab scrolling to section should enable. How can I do it? Please help

Answer (score 5):

I found this worked

```
function testing(){
    //forcing fullPage.js to recalculate dimensions.
    setTimeout(function(){
        fullpage_api.reBuild(); 
    }, 500);
};
```

for me this didn't work

```
$.fn.fullpage.reBuild();
```

Comment: Great answer. It is also useful when initially image in a section doesn't have the height set. For example because it's height is 50% of screen or only width is set. So I ensured that rebuild() is called also after images are loaded and now I don't have any issues with wrong section height nor srolling not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

For react users, this is the solution I found, that works best.
You need to save the `fullpageApi` from the `render` method, in state.
And then, take advantage of the useEffect to call the rebuild method.

I was using it inside the `render()`, but then I was getting a lot of weird behaviours, because the `rebuild()` was being called in every other page state update.

```
const [fullPageApi, setFullPageApi] = useState<fullpageApi>();

useEffect(() => {
    if (fullPageApi){
        setTimeout(function () {
            fullPageApi.reBuild();
        }, 1000);
    }
}, [fullPageApi]);

// (...)

// Component example
<ReactFullpage
    scrollOverflow
    navigation
    render={({ fullpageApi }) => {
        if (!fullPageApi) setFullPageApi(fullpageApi);
            return (
                <ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
                    <YourComponent />
                </ReactFullpage.Wrapper>
            );
        }
      }
/>
```